# Copy file to local google storage via command line (like gsutil cp)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

To emulate production, I want to copy a file to my local google storage (app_default_bucket) maintained by the app engine launcher.  This is performed via 'gsutil cp' in production.  I would like to do the same locally.   Possible?

I would like to avoid writing an app just for local use.

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible.

Comment: I was looking the same and finally I came up with solution described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395399/how-to-rsync-local-directory-with-google-cloud-storage-on-development-server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since GCS local storage (localhost:8000/_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket) is mapped to /tmp/storage directory (at least on Linux) and [cp command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) supports directory destination, copying files from a bucket to local storage is just a matter of:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://[my-bucket] /tmp/storage
```